# Search for owning NuGet Package of an assembly in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have an assembly that is causing me problems (Sigil v4.7).  I can see that it is in my project (via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and Object Browser).

But I can't figure out what NuGet package brought it in.

Visual Studio has a Tree View of packages:

[image: NuGet Dependencies]

But short of drilling all the way down all of them, I cannot find a way to see which package is causing an assembly to be included in my project.

**Is there a way to search to find which NuGet Package caused Sigil 4.7 to be added to my project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can search for dependencies by name in the solution explorer:
[image: Solution Explorer]

If you can't find it there, you can look at the `<Project>.deps.json` file in the `bin\<Configuration>\<Platform>` folder.

For example, I have a project called `Potato.csproj` building in `Debug` for net core 3.0, so the file is `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Potato.deps.json`

It lists all dependencies, as well as what project a dependency came from.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: Does not work for me, searching like that only shows the top-level packages.

Comment: Fixed mine by clicking on the small arrow on the right of the search and ticking the necessary option to search child packages.

Comment: @EduardG I had to do the same, although for me in VS22 (17.6.11) I had to check both 'Search within external items' for the child-level dependencies to appear.